# Tests stop running when elm.json file is changed from application to package

Tags: elm, elm-test

I'm having an issue with the https://github.com/Martouta/elm-emojis-converter. When I run the tests (In CircleCI, with cd /root/project/tests && elm-test), they work fine with the elm.json file as an application. However, when I change the elm.json file to make the project a package type, the tests stop running, and I get the following error:

```
Failed to run `elm-json solve`:
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/lib/package/mod.rs:251:73
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

You can see the change in this PR: https://github.com/Martouta/elm-emojis-converter/pull/5

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this error and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no clue why but it got fixed by updating from elm-test version 1.X to 2.X  I got to that conclusion testing locally ‍♀️ https://github.com/Martouta/elm-emojis-converter/pull/5/commits/741d43c1aaa5b60c923058e0428c2bad3e9b9502